# Android ProgressDialog while having long UI task

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask

I have a long string to set to an EditText and I need to show a ProgressDialog to inform user about delayed task:

```
String s="very long text, about 100kb...";
EditText edt;
edt=findViewByID(.....);
edt.setText(s); // this takes lots of time
```

I tried to put this in AsyncTask and show a ProgressDialog but the problem is **edt.setText(s)** should be run in **UI thread** and it will halt displaying progress dialog, so what should I do?

Comment: run `setText` in `onPostExecute` and show your dialog in in `onPreExecute`

Answer (score 3):

define as a class variable;

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

now in

```
oncreate() define

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
```

now ....just before starting async task ....

```
progressDialog.setMessage("creating profile...");
            progressDialog.show();
```

in post execute or whenever you want to stop progress dialog...

call this...

```
private void cancelDialoag() {
        AppLog.i("in method cancelDialoag");
        try {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            AppLog.e("dialoag is still open");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not update the UI in the Main thread so try to update your edittext in `onPostExecute` as below.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   super.onPostExecute();
   edt.setText(s);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As nitesh goel and GrlsHu suggested make the progress dialog a member of your Activity and update it in the main UI thread which is your activity thread. And update the edittext in the asynctask.like this:

Define the progress dialog in the activity:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity
{
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
}
```

And update it after the asynctaks is completed:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
     super.onPostExecute();
     edt.setText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ProgressDialog, why don't you try setCancelable(false) on DialogFragment?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use `append(CharSequence text, int start, int end)` in AsyncTask. separate the long string to slices of substrings. Then the UI will not be blocked.